# [True/False]The polynomial $x^4+7x^3−13x^2+11x$ has exactly one real root.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> [True/False]The polynomial $x^4+7x^3−13x^2+11x$ has exactly one real
>   root.

I want to solve it without drawing the graph. Here is my idea. Note that $f(1)=1+7-13+11=6>0$ and $f(-1)=1-7-13-11=-30<0$

So we have at least one real root. Now since degree is $4$ we have $4$ roots but rest three can not be complex as they occur in pairs, so we must have another real root.

**So the statement is False**

Am I right?

Thanks for reading and all the help.

Comment: How do you know the root is not a double root?

Comment: There are at least two. $0$ and one real root of $x^3+7x^2-13x+11$.

Comment: You are right, but the root $x=0$ is even more obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your result is correct (how to improve the actual argumentation is sufficiently discussed within the comments of this answer). It can be done in another by noting that
$$f(x)=x^4+7x^3-12x^2+11x=x\cdot(x^3+7x^2-12x+11)=x\cdot g(x)$$
$f(x)$ has one real root at $x=0$. Now, $g(x)$ is of degree $3$ and every polynomial of degree $3$ has at least one real root by the Intermediate Value Theorem since $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}g(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$.

Thus, $f(x)$ has at least two real roots.

Comment: The answer that the OP reached is correct, but I feel that saying they are right is not entirely right, as the reasoning is very flawed.

Comment: @Arthur Where could my approach possibly go wrong? I think my approach does not cover the fact the roots can have multiplicity 2 but even if that is the case, we would still have two real roots. right? It would be great of you, if you can clarify this last doubt of mine

Comment: @StammeringMathematician It might be enough to add that the (at least) one real root within the interval $[-1,1]$ is precisely at $x=0$ and clearly isn't of multiplicity $2$.

Comment: I guess you meant to say Intermediate Value theorem. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Of course! Edited.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician $x^2(x^2+1)$ has a real root on the interval $[-1, 1]$. Then the exact same argument as the one you use in your answer will "prove" that there must be another root (there are three remaining roots, and we can't have that none of them are real), but there isn't one.

Comment: @Arthur So when we say "exactly one root" we mean one root counting multiplicity?

Comment: @Arthur I got it. I understand why my argument is flawed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whether we count multiple roots or not is technically up to the original problem author. Conventions vary. But yes, I would think that the intended interpretation is to count distinct roots. If the intended interpretation is to count with multiplicity, then you don't even need to look for roots in the first place. You just know that there can only be $0, 2$ or $4$ non-real roots, and therefore there cannot be exactly one real root. That's a bit boring, and it would seem rather pointless to give a concrete polynomial to work with.

Comment: I suppose you should have mentioned that the root of $x^3+7x^2-12x+11$ is clearly different from $x=0$.